# Does the windows 7 loopback adapter support multicast?

Tags: .net, windows-7, multicast, loopback

We need to be able to run a subset of a large system on a laptop for the sales team to demo. The systems uses multicast but, when installed on a laptop with no network other than the loopback adapter enabled the multicasting does not work. The same behaviour is also seen in some very small test programs.

According to the system network information multicast is supported by the loopback adapter, and that correlates with the routing table. But, we're seeing nothing get through.

Any ideas? This is all with w7 professional, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the Microsoft Loopback adapter does support multicast on both Windows XP and Windows 7. I'd suggest there is something specific about your set-up that is making it fail.

I've also found the following:

For multicast to work, there must be at least one network adapter on which TCP/IP is enabled and configured with a valid IP address, and that adapter must also be physically plugged into a live network. (The Microsoft Loopback adapter simulates a live network.) The above must be satisfied even if you want multicast only on the local host.

Maybe your answer is to connect the laptop's Ethernet to a powered hub and configure it with a static IP address. That should get multicasting working - at the expense of carrying two boxes around instead of one.